# IOS Sprite Kit Game Center Can't Add Leaderboard in Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, game-center, leaderboard

I am developing a simple 2D sprite kit game for IOS. I added a leaderboard and some demo accounts to test it out and it all worked fine.

Yesterday, i decided it was time to release version 1.0 of the app and before i submitted the app for review i deleted the existing leaderboard just to make sure no fake scores from my demo accounts remain.

I then submitted the app for review and later when i tried to add a new leaderboard, the process works normally until i reach the point where i press save (to make the leaderboard active) but the button is greyed out no matter what i do. i read the documentation and searched online for similar cases and tried all of the following:

1. Made sure game center is enabled
2. chose single leaderboard
3. made sure the leaderbard reference name is correct
4. made sure the leaderboard Id is correct
5. Chose a score format
6. made sure to write the score range in numbers
7. create a localization language

however, the save button remains grey and i can not add a leaderboard. i tried today as well, the original leaderboard was deleted and stil the same issue. now when i try to play my game (on my test device) when i reach the end and the score should be submitted, the game crashes (since there is no leaderboard and my code submits the score at this point)

If my game is accepted and goes online it wouldn't be a good thing to have it crashing from version 1.0. I do not know what is causing this and what i can do to solve it, would appreciate any help.

Thank you